# How to add border bottom hover effect in Bootstrap navbar?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I am trying to add border bottom hover effect to the navbar in bootstrap like this

[image]

But I am getting my result like this

[image]

I need to move the border bottom all the way to the navbar bottom.

```css
.nav-link:visited,
.nav-link:link {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1bcfc6;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark ">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./product.html">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Can you share demo link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is caused by the default padding set by the Bootstrap classes on the navbar element. You can override them using the [Bootstrap classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) `pb-0` and `pt-0`. Padding Bottom 0 and Padding Top 0 are the expansions of these classes. You might just need the pb-0 but pt-0 so that the text is not spaced unevenly on the vertical side.

View the below output in full screen as the navbar collapses on smaller screen.

```css
.nav-link:visited,
.nav-link:link {
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #1bcfc6;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark pt-0 pb-0">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./home.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./about.html">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./product.html">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="./contact.html">Contact Us</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</nav>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve that would be to override the bootstrap-padding of the navbar like this:

```
.navbar {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to inspect and get to know the `padding`s and `margin`s in **Bootstrap** `nav`, `ul`, `li`, `a` etc.

If you use `border`, it will take all the space including the `padding`, so you can't achieve this using `border`. Generally, we use CSS pseudo-elements for this kinda work, like CSS `::before` or `::after` here is a simple example of this, I hope it would help you achieve what you want.

```html
<style>
  .nav {
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }

  .nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 8px 15px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #000;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: all .3s ease;

    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .nav a:hover,
  .nav a.active {
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
  }

  .nav a::before {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    width: calc(100% - 20px);
    height: 3px;
    background: orange;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease;
  }

  .nav a.active::before,
  .nav a:hover::before {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  }
</style>


<div class="nav">
  <a href="#">item-1</a>
  <a href="#">item-2</a>
  <a href="#" class="active">item-3</a>
  <a href="#">item-4</a>
  <a href="#">item-5</a>
</div>
```